# Convert points to percentage

Tags: html

I've the below HTML

```
<colspec colwidth="20pt" colname="c1"/>
<colspec colwidth="70pt" colname="c2"/>
<colspec colwidth="10pt" colname="c3"/>
<colspec colwidth="20pt" colname="c4"/>
<colspec colwidth="75pt" colname="c5"/>
```

I'm unable to know how to convert the colwidth to percentage, when I sum these colwidths, it is exceeding 200pt (assuming 1pt=1%), it is exceeding the table size.

Could someone please help me with this?

Also can you please let me know how I can use

```
 colsep="1" rowsep="1"
```

Comment: colspec width in pts / container width in pts * 100... and don't assume 1pt is 1%

Comment: I am not able to find any info on a `colspec` tag. I see a reference to a `colspec` attribute on the never adopted HTML 3.0 spec. http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/tables.html . Is this a CALS table thing?

Comment: The code is surely not HTML. Is it EAD? Please specify this by editing the question and retagging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure for this. But I think, you can not gives `colwidth` in percentage.

```
COLWIDTH Units may be “pt,” “cm,” “in,” and an * for proportional measures, such as “5*”.
```

[Read this document](http://eadiva.com/colspec/)

Answer (score 0):

it will be like... You can gain it using Colwidth / total of columns width * 100 

 I.e. (20/195) * 100

```
10.26 %
35.89 %
5.13 %
10.26 %
38.46 %
```